# Nest.js WebSocket returns Transport unknown

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket, nestjs

I have backend on NestJS and frontend on Angular 8. When I try connect websocket, backend returns:
`{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`

I have NestJS 7.4.3:

```
"@nestjs/common": "~7.4.3",
"@nestjs/core": "~7.4.3",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "~7.4.3",
"@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^7.4.3",
"@nestjs/websockets": "^7.4.3",
"@types/socket.io": "^2.1.11",
```

Gateqay:

```
@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/ws', transports: ['polling', 'websocket'] })
```

why is it not working?

Comment: Can you show how you're connecting on the front end?

Comment: const ws = new SockJS(this.apiPath + this.webSocketEndPoint);
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
this.stompClient.connect({userId, token}, () => this.initSubscribes(), this.errorCallBack);

Comment: [Seems like it may be a miss between Socket.IO and SocksJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582787/sockjs-connected-as-websocket-but-nothing-going-through)